# prepared statement method.. confused

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, statements

I don't know what's missing or why it isn't displaying data. My code is working if I'm not using prepared statements. When I used prepared statements, it seems that code is not working anymore.

**db.php**

```
Class Database{


public $mysqli;
public function __construct($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name){

    $this->con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

}

    public function selectUserInfo($id){

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE os_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
        if($stmt->execute() == FALSE){
            trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }else{
            $data = array();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }

}
}
```

**config.php**

```
define("DBHOST","somehost");
define("DBUSER","someroot");
define("DBPASS","somepassword");
define("DB","my_database");
```

this is how I would displayed it at my page.

```
require 'global/db.php';
require_once 'config.php';
$db = new Database(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DB);
$data = $db->selectUserInfo($_GET['name']);
foreach ($data as $key) {
    # code...
    echo $key['os_fname'];
}
```

Comment: No error messages? Are you passing a GET parameter named `name`? If so, are there rows in your DB with `osd_id` equal to that parameter?

Comment: it does not display error message.. I would like to display a value of 1 in my $_GET['name']

Comment: @Edgar So when you open the *page*, do you have `?name=1` in the URL?

Comment: @vinodadhikary No it isn't. Each `$key` is a row

Comment: @Phil yep.. i do have name=1 in my url

Comment: @Edgar ... and do you have rows in your database `users` table with `os_id` equal to 1?

Comment: @Phil yes.. I also have a data with ID equal to 1

Comment: Change `if($stmt->execute() == FALSE){` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){` and `$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);` to `$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);`

Comment: already changed to what you said.. still it doesn't display data O.o

Comment: @Edgar check my code and lets see if u get any error. also if you are currently getting any error kindly post the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have defined, that the issue was with your `foreach`.

What is wrong is with how you're reading it, `fetch` does not have associative properties so need to use the `bind_result`.

Here is a hack that is also suggested at the [`fetch` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

```
public function selectUserInfo($id)
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE os_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    if(!$stmt->execute())
    {
        trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        $bindVarArray = array();
        $data = array();
        $result;
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
        while ($column = $meta->fetch_field())
        {
            $columnName = str_replace(' ', '_', $column->name);
            $bindVarArray[] = &$result[$columnName];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $bindVarArray);

        $index = 0;
        while ($stmt->fetch() != null)
        {
            foreach ($result as $k => $v)
            {
                $data[$index][$k] = $v;
            }
            $index++;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Then you can use your `foreach` to read it like this:

```
foreach ($data as $result)
{
    echo $result['os_fname'], ' => ', $result['os_lname'], "\n";
}
```

And you can always use `print_r` to see how your resulting array is:

```
print_r($data);
```

Comment: @Edgar Then look at the error_log file you probably forgot to close a variable. Or post the content of `global/db.php` and `config.php` removing any sensitive data such as password, username, ip etc.

Comment: i edited my post above..
it displayed Array ( [0] => Edgar ) when I removed my foreach and changed it to print_r

Comment: @Edgar ;) there you go, your problem is that you're not associating your array hence it will not have `$key['os_fname']` you have to use `$stmt->bind_result($fname);` and declared on your query all the fields you want to read like I have on my example or call the variable by the index. `foreach ($data as $value) echo $value;` or `echo $data[0], .... rest of columns ..., $data[1], "\n";`

Comment: so code would be like this ? am I correct ?

 if ($stmt->execute())
     {
         $data = array();
         $result = $stmt->bind_result($fname, $lname, $email);
         while($stmt->fetch())
         {
             $data[] = $result;
         }
         return $data;
     }

Comment: @Edgar see update its a hack to automatically read the fields.

Answer (score -3):

your od_id type in DB is string or integer? if a integer

```
public function selectUserInfo($id){

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE os_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);//use 'i' instead of 's'

    if($stmt->execute() == FALSE){
        trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }else{
        $data = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

}