# How to fetch assoc array while using mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

To make sure my database is secure I'm using prepare statements. Here is my code:

```
//connecting to MySql database
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbname");
// checking database connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE emb=? LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $emb);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Now I want to know how can I use ASSOC fetch array

```
$embInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I want this so that I can just put something like below to get values

```
$embInfo['name']
```

and

```
$embInfo['email']
```

Comment: I guess this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846583/mysqli-fetch-array-prepared-statement-and-like-statement             And better move to PDO

Comment: if the mysqlnd is not available then you need to define all fields and use bind_result or [use something like this to dynamically define the fields.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501513/prepared-statment-method-confused/18502088#18502088)

Comment: What if I use `mysqli-stmt.get-result`? Will this help? Someone suggested this in stackoverflow chat.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
//connecting to MySql database
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbname");
// checking database connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE emb=? LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $emb);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


while($embInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  echo 'My name is '.$embInfo['name'].'and my email is '.$embInfo['email'].'<br/>';

}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Answer (score -3):

May i suggest an alternative

```
{
  $server = '';
  $user = '';
  $pass = '';
  $db = '';

  // connect to the database
  $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

  // show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

  $club=$_POST'club'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE club = '$club'";
  $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['player'];
  }
  }
```

Comment: But I think this is not secure. SQL injections can destroy database through this code. This is the reason why I am trying to use prepared statements.

Comment: $club = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['club']);

try using this

Comment: @sushruth-sv real escape string is outdated and you are suggesting mysql which is deprecated. I cannot understand what are you trying to say. You should know prepare that method is most secure these days.

Comment: both more secure & faster due to the fact, the MySQL Engine is able to reuse it's old execution plan for consecutive queries